# Network Load Balancer not works

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs, aws-application-load-balancer

I use ECS for run container. I have 2 images. FrontEnd, BackEnd

Flow looks: Internet -80,443-> FrontEnd -8080-> BackEnd
Now I works on the one EC2, so user a service discovery and provide for frontend environment value address to make connection between ends.

Now I want change this to load balancer to have possibility to scale.
I run the new ECS service of BackEnd and on the configuration I choose to use network load balancer with listen on port TCP 8080 port. Configure Instance Target group to listen also the 8080 port.
However service up task and task failed with error: *Task failed ELB health checks in (target-group*

I have open open port 8080 in Security Group which is used by the EC2.

Any ideas what is wrong? In order to question i don't want to use the application load balancer due that FrontEnd expect that the address which i put in environments direct to only one IP address. ALB left two.

I fully configure the fist Load Balancer Internet > FrontEnd using Application Load Balancer. Works perfectly.
I expect to do the same on the FrontEnd -> BackEnd but using different LB network load balancer.

Comment: Standard NLB troubleshooting [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/network/load-balancer-troubleshooting.html). Have you run through these steps?

Comment: Yes, but not help.
However I find another solution. Needs to create alb for the backend and then create nlb behind alb. Then you have a static IP for the fronend and all works fine.
This video was very helpful to do that https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TR9acyhXCNo&ab_channel=Cloud4DevOps